# Controlling which tests run using pytest

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I'm considering converting some `unittest.TestCase` tests into Pytest ones to take advantage of Pytest's fixtures. One feature of `unittest` that I wasn't able to easily find the equivalent of in Pytest, however, is the ability to create testing suites and run them. I currently often do something like this:

```
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual("hello".upper(), "HELLO")

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    # suite.addTest(TestSomething('test_1'))
    suite.addTest(TestSomething('test_2'))
    runner = unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(suite)
```

By commenting in and out the lines with `addTest`, I can easily select which tests to run. How would I do something similar with Pytest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-k` argument to run specific tests. For example

```
# put this in test.py
import unittest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual("hello".upper(), "HELLO")

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)
```

Running all tests in the class `TestSomething` can be done like this:

```
py.test test.py -k TestSomething
```

Running only `test_2`:

```
py.test test.py -k "TestSomething and test_2"
```

More examples in the [documentation](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/usage.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another way to go is to use special test names. These can be configures in the pytest.ini file.

```
# content of pytest.ini
# can also be defined in tox.ini or setup.cfg file, although the section
# name in setup.cfg files should be "tool:pytest"
[pytest]
python_files=check_*.py
python_classes=Check
python_functions=*_check
```

Another way is to take action in conftest.py. In this example the collect_ignore config variable is used. It is a list of test paths that are to be ignored. In this example test_somthing.py is always ignored for collection. test_other_module_py2.py is ignored if we are testing with a python 3.

```
# content of conftest.py
import sys

collect_ignore = ["test_something/test_something.py"]
if sys.version_info[0] > 2:
    collect_ignore.append("test_other/test_other_module_py2.py")
```

Since pytest 2.6 it is also possible to omit classes from test registration like this:

```
# Will not be discovered as a test
class TestClass:
    __test__ = False
```

These examples were loosely taken from the documentation of pytest chapter [Changing standard (Python) test discovery](http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/pythoncollection.html)

Comment: does `collect_ignore` need to be in a `conftest.py` file? Can it be put directly in a test module?

Comment: I don't think this is easily possible, since collect_ignore is a variable defined in conftest.py and then to be looked up there by pytest init on runtime. But you could taint your classes like I am pointing out in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `-k` filters, you can name specific test classes or cases you want to run,

```
py.test test.py::TestSomething::test_2
```

Would run just `test_2`

Answer (score 1):

Think the best way to do this is to use custom pytest markers.
You should mark specific tests (which you want to run) with 
`@pytest.mark.mymarkername`

And run only tests with the custom marker using command:
`py.test -v -m mymarkername`

Here you can find more info regarding markers:
http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/example/markers.html

Comment: suppose I have a combinations custom markers e.g. slow and fast. Is there a way to run a particular test always irrespective of selection of marker? say `def test_sanity()....` run this test always irrespective of selection filter?

Answer (score 0):

Building on [mbatchkarov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419338/mbatchkarov)'s answer, since the names of my tests can get quite lengthy, I would like to still be able to select tests by commenting in and out lines and hitting "Cntrl+B" in Sublime (or "Cntrl+R" using the Atom Runner). One way to do this is as follows:

```
import unittest
import pytest

class TestSomething(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_1(self):
        self.assertEqual("hello".upper(), "HELLO")

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertEqual(1+1, 2)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tests_to_run = []
#   tests_to_run.append('TestSomething and test_1')
    tests_to_run.append('TestSomething and test_2')
    tests_to_run = " or ".join(tests_to_run)
    args = [__file__, '-k', tests_to_run]
    pytest.main(args)
```

The idea behind this is that because Pytest accepts a string expression to match tests (rather than just a list of tests), one must generate a list of expressions matching one test only, and concatenate them using `or`.